# Why can't I drill down from column to bar?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts has a lovely demo of a chart that [drills down from columns to pies](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/across-types/). But if I try to switch things up so it uses bars instead of pies, I get [bars and then bars](http://jsfiddle.net/amandabee/SeY63/1/), not columns and then bars:

```
$(function () {

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar' //change this to "pie" and it works just fine. 
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }],
        type: 'column'
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
}) });
```

Is it possible to switch from columns to bars when I drill down?

Comment: I think this is close to what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/zauberware/GfhLB/3/

Comment: You cannot switch between inverted chart, so you need to destroy and create new chart.

Comment: @AndrewSellenrick That's basically what I have. I can drill down to a pie chart fine. But I can't drill down to bars.